# Is it posssible to calculate the intersection area of rectangles with sweep Line and Interval or Segment Tree

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, intervals

I am curently working on automatic label placement, so for evaluating a model, one metric is to calculate the Area A:

A is the sum of every part of a rectangle covered by another. So if two rectangle overlap, A = 2 * Arectangle, if three rectangle overlap A = 3 * Arectangle, ...

Because i am working in real time, i need to calculate this as fast as I can, so I went with a sweep line for the x-axis. But I don't understand how can i use an interval or a segment Tree to calculate the length for the x point. So I wanted to know if there is a way to use one of these tree or if i am condamned to use another sweepline on the y axis.

Here is an example for the 1d problem:

[image]

Here the return value should be :
L = 2 * (8-5) + (8-7) + 2 * (10 - 8) + 2 * (18 - 17) = 6 + 1 + 4 + 2 = 13

Comment: I'm very confused. 1) What you call rectangles, are they actually segments on a line? If not, I don't see how you use that they are 2D rectangles. 2) What is `Arectangle`? 3) So for each segment covered more than once you compute how many rectangles cover it; and then you compute the sum of such values over all such segments? Why do you need segment tree for that? It can be done with a simple sorting. 4) `Because i am working in real time` what is your exact model? Segments can appear and disappear at any time and in any order and you have to answer the query?

Comment: Sry if I wasn't clear. 1) The use of sweep line algorithme let us transform the problem into a 1-dimension one which is to find the length like i calculated in my post. Then we multiply it with the dx value to find the area of intersecting rectangles for the dx gap(event are left and right point of rectangle) 2)Arectangle is the area of a rectangle, in the example i take identical rectangles that i overlaped. 3)The Tree permit to have, if i have understand it correctly, an update in log(n) time and the awnser in O(1). 4) Real time just mean that i need to calculate this at high frequency

Comment: I see. I'm not sure they'll be faster, but you can take a look at quadtrees.